# Unrecognized archive format when trying to extract content from a TAR archive

Tags: linux, macos, tar

I have an uncompressed TAR file created on Linux.

If I use `less` to view the file I can see all the data; mostly code files. However if I try to decompress it I get the following error:

> tar: Unrecognized archive format error.

If I do a `file thetarfile.tar` I get the type data.

How can I extract the file?

Comment: What command are you using to decompress it?  Note tar is not a compression format, it is an archive format - the data is stored the same size as the origin.

Comment: I am trying with this tar -xvf tarfile.tar

Comment: Does `tar tf tarfile.tar` list the files expected in the tar?

Comment: No it does not. Same error I am afraid

Comment: When you say you can see the data, do you mean you can see php script files in plain text?  My guess would be that the backup failed from Drupal and so it isn't recognised as a proper tar.

Comment: Yes, that is what I can see. If I use tail I can see the end of the tar file is correct too. I think that it combined all the files and then failed, then sent me the entire combined file. But I am wondering is there is a way to reverse it, so the files are split into prober files again ?

Comment: A tar file includes details of each file - including filenames and lengths - before the data.  If those headers are intact, then tar should work.  Some probably are, so it is a case of examining the file and seeing what parts can be recovered.  Or doing the backup again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to save what is still possible with the utility `cpio`.
(*GNU cpio copies files into or out of a cpio or tar archive...*)

The command below should do the job  extracting the files and recreating the directory tree:

```
      cpio -ivd -H tar < myfile.tar
```

Ps> Work in a safe place (directory).

In details:

- `-i` or `--extract` Run in [copy-in mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/cpio/manual/cpio.html#Copy_002din-mode).
- `-d` or `--make-directories`  Create leading directories where needed.
  (by default it doesn't create directory)
- `-v` or `--verbose` as often write more informations, this time it lists the files processed.
- `-H format` or `--format=format`  Use archive format *format*.

Resume:
It's *almost* a complete `tar` file. It has not the magic number in the header, it has the finals signature. Moreover you can read the part with text files (when you use less) so without compression. It's corrupted. Why (if because the server doesn't finish the job or it was transferred corrupting some parts) is secondary. **If you can generate it again it's better.** If not you can try what above or below...

References:
You can find the help on the [site of **cpio**](http://www.gnu.org/software/cpio/manual/cpio.html) or on the [mac site](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cpio.1.html) too.
Full [option list](http://www.gnu.org/software/cpio/manual/cpio.html#Options)

---

Alternatives:

- Following [this
  post](http://riaschissl.bestsolution.at/2014/03/repost-how-to-repair-corrupt-tar-archives/)
  and downloading this [perl script](http://www.bestsolution.at/documents/find_tar_headers.pl.bz2),
  after that you decompress  it (with `bunzip2
  find_tar_headers.pl.bz2`) you can use it:

  ```
  perl find_tar_headers.pl yourfile.tar
  ```

  it will answer with a series of lines as

  > yourfile.tar:**12345**:dir/subdir/yourfile:126344
  >   yourfile.tar:20578:dir/subdir/yourfile:123453   ...

  read the 1st number, in this case **12345** and what follows should solve your problem

  ```
  tail -c +12345 yourfile.tar > extracted_tail_yourfile.tar
  tar xf extracted_tail_yourfile.tar
  ```
- `75 73 74 61 72 00 30 30` or `75 73 74 61 72 20 20 00` are the signatures for a tar file. (according with [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)). You can write one of them at the offset 257 on a copy of your file with an hexadecimal editor or with `dd` and it will be recognized as a `tar` file. Probably you will be able to extract something too,  **but it will be still corrupted**: it's better if you can generate it again.

Answer (score 1):

Just because a file has a tar or tgz suffix does not make it a tar file.

You can check the magic number in the file header with the file command:

```
file myfile
```

And it will report the type of file.  It could be zip format, bzip format or even cpio.

If it returns "data" then it may not be a known archive or not an archive at all.

Comment: Yeah, it does return data as I wrote in my question. I can see all the content of the files if I view the file in less.

Comment: tar and cpio are just standardized formats for combining files into a single archive.  A programmer is free to create their own format, and this may be what you are seeing.  A custom format archive.  Unless you can id which program created the archive, you may be out of luck.  Ask for another archive in a standard format.

Comment: The program is the Backup and Migrate module in Drupal. I have 2 other tar files of two other site on the same server. These are working normally.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a number of things causing the TAR to be seen as corrupt. If it were a partially completed archive it would simply not be complete but at least un-TAR to a point. If `file thetarfile.tar` returns “data” it could be that it is a compressed archive?

One idea is to see if perhaps there is some kind of carriage return/line break issue. And that can possibly be solved via [`dos2unix`](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/dos2unix-removing-hidden-windows-characters-from-files/), a utility in Linux/Unix that converts file carriage returns/line breaks into Linux compatible breaks. To use it just do this the following.

First, install `dos2unix`. Unclear what system you are attempting to do this on, but in Ubuntu you could run this `aptitude` command to install it from a repository:

```
sudo aptitude install dos2unix
```

Now create a copy of the original `.tar` to test it like this:

```
cp tarfile.tar tarfile_TEST.tar
```

Now with `dos2unix` just run this command:

```
dos2unix tarfile_TEST.tar
```

The output would be something like this:

```
dos2unix: converting file tarfile_TEST.tar to UNIX format ...
```

Then try to decompress the contents of that TAR file like this:

```
tar -xf tarfile_TEST.tar
```

Now if you need to install `dos2unix` in Mac OS X, there [are tips here on how to handle that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373888/converting-newline-formatting-from-mac-to-windows). But this all is a hunch on my part; don’t delve too deep down this theoretical rabbit hole unless it shows itself to be a true solution.